# MYSQL query select from table and order by date and other field. prioritize other field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table called Agenda:

```
ID:visible:sticky:startdate
 1:      1:     1:2014-03-08
 2:      1:     0:2014-02-25
 3:      1:     0:2014-02-27
 4:      1:     0:2014-02-20
 5:      1:     0:2014-03-12

(ID->int, visible->tinyint, sticky->tinyint, startdate->date)
```

I am running the following query to get the next three agenda items by date, working fine of course. Returning ID's 4,2,3

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM agenda 
   WHERE visible 
     AND startdate >= "2014-02-12" 
ORDER BY startdate ASC 
   LIMIT 3
```

But what I would like is to prioritize fields that have sticky = 1, if there are fields that have it set they should be in the results and be accounted for in the ORDER BY. So what I would like it to return is ID's 4,2,1

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Are you sure visible is TINYINT and not BOOL? Also, see FIELD()

Comment: visible is in this case a TINYINT but it acts as a BOOL. It is 1 or 0 so the query WHERE visible AND is working

Comment: @tvgemert `WHERE (visible 
   AND startdate >= "2014-02-12") OR sticky = 1` ?

Comment: I didn't know that! You live and learn.

Comment: Well... BOOL would be more logical actually in this case ;) but this makes it possible to have "other statuses" from 1 or 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM 
  agenda
  WHERE visible
  AND startdate >= "2014-02-12"
  ORDER BY sticky DESC, startdate ASC
  LIMIT 3
) subquery
ORDER BY startdate ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

this will set the sticky at the top of the results, as far as I know there is no way to include them midway, you could always use 2 query's and combine the results in an array which you could then sort by date.

```
SELECT *
FROM agenda
WHERE visible
AND startdate >= "2014-02-12"
ORDER BY sticky DESC , startdate ASC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: But that is not working because it would first ORDER BY startdate and after that sticky. I want sticky to be always included if it is 1

Comment: Same, but other way around. Creating the array and sorting it is an option, but it should be possible using SQL right?